# do not adding to database in java jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I want to add a person with name and password to the database with a register button on reg.html. User fill username and password and then press register button and information will be added to database. But my code is not work properly.

```
public void addPerson(String username, String password) {
    if (con == null) {
        System.out.println("no connection");
        connect();
    }
    try {
        Statement state = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('" +      username + "', '" + password + "'");
        rs.next();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

This is the reg.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<jsp:useBean id="bean1" scope="session" class="veri.kisi" />
<jsp:setProperty name="bean1" property="username"/>    
<jsp:setProperty name="bean1" property="password" />

</body>
</html>
```

This is the kisi.java

```
public void insertPerson() {
    DatabaseLayer layer = new DatabaseLayer();
    layer.addPerson(username, password);
}
```

Comment: `INSERT` is not a *query*. Check your log files, because you have a stacktrace telling you that.

Comment: Also, **do not** use string concatenation to build a SQL statement using user-supplied strings. See [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: And **do not** store user passwords in plain text.  That is *grossly irresponsible* to your users.  Obscure the passwords behind a 1-way hash so that even you as the system owner can't read or recover them in any way.

Comment: how can i have to change my code ?

Comment: String query = "insert into users(col1,col2,...)" + "values('" + c1 + "','" + c21+ "',...)"; state.executeUpdate(query);

Comment: Read tutorials of JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a note of the above comments given by others, they can prove to be vital to make your code secured while inserting data in database from online sources.

```
 public void addPerson(String username, String password) {
if (con == null) {
    System.out.println("no connection");
    connect();
}
try {
    Statement state = con.createStatement();
    state.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('" +      username + "', '" + password + "'");


} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

}

}
```

The ResultSet object is used to iterate over the rows of tables in database, not to insert queries into database.

Comment: rs.nex() gave an error. I deleted it. After that, I run and it still not working

Comment: @burak nurçiçek sorry for my mistake to leave rs.next(), it was just a typing mistake of mine, Could you tell me why isn't it working, so that i can try to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Before doing any updaes i would suggest that you set `con.autocommit` to false. Then Use `state.executeUpdate();` It will return an int type. Check if that int is > 0. and then only do a commit job by calling `con.commit()`.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `ResultSet` since insert is not query. For this you may use PreparedStatement. Replace `try` block code with the following lines.

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into users values (?,?)");
ps.setString(1, username);
ps.setString(2, password);
ps.execute();
```